# How to reference CSS animation with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a css animation that slides in a title when a page loads. How do I make it so that the Title will Slide out when I click a link, and the next Title will slide in? (Using Javascript)

It is most likely very simple but I am very new to this.

Comment: Have a class trigger the animation, and apply the class dynamically with JavaScript: `element.classList.add('example-animation-class')`

Comment: Also, please post your code.

Comment: I wonder if a `transition` is a better fit than an animation for a simple "slide" effect

Comment: Sorry! Here is my code. https://jsfiddle.net/yk7w2zt2/

Answer (score 0):

> As you have not provided any code, i have no codebase to develop upon,
>   so have created a sample demonstrating iterating titles. You can use
>   your existing slide animation on top of this to get your desired
>   output.

HTML
`<div id="titleHolder"></div>`

CSS

```
.title{
  font-size:18px;
  cursor:pointer
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const titles = ['StackOverflow', 'StackExchange', 'AskDifferent', 'Ask Ubuntu'];
const titlesLenght = titles.length;

const getTitleDomId = (title, index) => `${title}-${index}`;

const getTitleDom = (title, index) => `<span class="title ${index === 0 ? '' : 'hidden'}" id="${getTitleDomId(title, index)}" onclick="slideNext(${index}, ${index === titlesLenght -1 ? 0 : index+1});">${title}</span>`;

window.slideNext = (index, nextIndex) => {
  document.getElementById(getTitleDomId(titles[index], index)).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(getTitleDomId(titles[nextIndex], nextIndex)).style.display = 'block';
};

for (let i = 0; i < titlesLenght; i++) {
  document.getElementById('titleHolder').innerHTML += getTitleDom(titles[i], i);
}
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/fcafdd59/)

> Make sure you supply your code with question for faster and more relevant answers.